# Access fileObj storeName or key collectionFS

Tags: angularjs, meteor, nginx, angular-meteor, collectionfs

How can I get in a call back after inserting a file using collectionFS the `key` value?

```
Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('success', fileObj);
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('url', fileObj.url());
      let url = fileObj.url('images');
      $scope.slideshows.url = `${url}`
      $scope.$apply();
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

I'm building a cms which handles file uploads to show in different apps, I'm able to see the uploaded file using `{{image.url}}` in the cms but I'm unable to view the images uploaded using this method in the other apps.

Every app is connecting to the same database and I'm uploading the images into my server using:

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: '/home/uploadedimages'})]
});
```

I'm then using nginx to serve those images so I can access them via `http://domain.com/uploadedimages`.

In order to fix my problem I need to somehow get the `key` value in this schema stored by collectionFS:

```
{
    "_id" : "5BEe4maLCMFtHAZAj",
    "original" : {
        "name" : "wantedposter.jpg",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-05-19T13:34:32.050Z"),
        "size" : 28828,
        "type" : "image/jpeg"
    },
    "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2016-05-19T21:30:54.299Z"),
    "copies" : {
        "images" : {
            "name" : "wantedposter.jpg",
            "type" : "image/jpeg",
            "size" : 28828,
            "key" : "images-5BEe4maLCMFtHAZAj-wantedposter.jpg",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-05-19T21:30:54Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-19T21:30:54Z")
        }
    }
}
```

So I can do `/uploadedimages/:key`

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to get the `key` value from collectionFS?

Comment: Normally you just use the `.url()` method of the CollectionFS object to display it.

Comment: I think I temporary found a solution by doing ```$scope.slideshows.url = `/uploadedimages/images-${fileObj._id}-${fileObj.name()}`;```